# Why does WP display the actual shortcode not the string that's meant to replace it?

Tags: shortcode

I'm learning how to create shortcodes. I have the following plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Foobar
 * @version 1.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Foobar
Plugin URI: www.example.com
Description: Shortcode something something
Author: Me
Version: 1.0
Author URI: www.example.com
*/

//[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );

?>
```

The plugin is activated:

[image: Screenshot showing activated wordpress plugin]

The shortcode is in the post:

[image: post editor]

I expect `[foobar]` to be replaced with "foo and bar". Instead the post is displayed as:

[image: screenshot of post]

What have I missed? Why isn't the short code tag being replaced?

Comment: And if you place it on its own line? Making sure it looks exactly as it should from the non-visual raw text view? And that all caching plugins are turned off? Also, the trailing `?>` is unnecessary and is considered bad practice as any whitespace afterwards can cause problems for some versions of PHP

Comment: I moved it to its own line. No caching plugins. No HTML tags etc. in the raw text view -- looks how it should be. Still the same behaviour.

Comment: hmmm and the plugin is activated on the same blog on the same server? This is highly suspicious, that code should work

Comment: in fact, I put the code on my own site and tested it, and it worked https://tomjn.com/hello/

Comment: Also, why is your Hello in all caps on the frontend? Are you sure you're not running various plugins on the content that're interfering? Or modified the frontend to not use `the_content`?

Comment: Yes, I had written another plugin that modified `the_content`.

Comment: In that case you need to use the `do_shortcode()` while filter the content.

Answer (score 2):

The cause was obvious. I had earlier created a plugin that uppercased the entire post. The shortcode was not recognised because it was in all caps -- just as the screenshot shows. Disabling that plugin allowed the shortcode to work as intended.

Comment: You can uppercase text using CSS via `text-transform: uppercase;`